# Parent object changes even if the copy of it is created while splice

Tags: javascript

I have a parent object `categories`, and a function that flattens and removes duplicate numbers inside the array.
But even though I make a copy the `categories` object (`let newObj = {...categories}`) and perform the above flatten function, it affects the parent `categories` object.

**Code:**

```
let categories = {
  Red: {
    Name: "Fire Flame",
    List: [
      ["1","5"],
      ["10","15"]
    ]
  },
  Blue: {
    Name: "Super Light",
    List: [
      ["1","5"],
      ["9","12"]
    ]
  },
  Custom: {
    List: [
      "Star Flash"
    ]
  }
}



  const submitData = () => {
    let obj = { ...categories };
    let types = Object.keys(obj);
    types.map((key) => {
      flattenAndUnique(key);
    });
    function flattenAndUnique(key) {
      let myList = obj[key].List;
      let resList = [];
      if (key !== "Custom") {
        myList.map(async (data, index) => {
          let min = Math.min(...data);
          let max = Math.max(...data);
          for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            resList.push(String(i));
          }
          const spliced = [...myList.splice(index, 1, resList)];
          let flatLevelArray = [].concat.apply([], myList);
          let uniqueLevelArray = flatLevelArray.filter(
            (v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i
          );
          obj = {
            ...obj,
            [key]: {
              ...obj[key],
              List: uniqueLevelArray,
            },
          };
          resList = [];
        });
      } else {
        let flatLevelArray = [].concat.apply([], myList);
        obj = {
          ...obj,
          Custom: {
            ...obj.Custom,
            List: flatLevelArray,
          },
        };
      }
    }
    console.log("final obj %% ===>", obj);
    console.log("Floors final &&&&", categories);
  };
  
  submitData()
```

sumbitData function actually flattend the array and removes duplicates. For eg,
If i have two array - [["1","4"] , ["11","13"]], the function transforms it into - ["1","2","3","4","11","12","13"]
which works fine,
My only issue is that my parent `categories` also changes.

Comment: what is the expected result? `{...foo}` does a shallow copy, any objects in `foo` will be references to the original.

Comment: Maybe it is because of a top level copy, Try using a deep copy method.

Comment: you almost *never* need to copy, and definitely not *deep copy*. that is not the issue.

Comment: @Mulan Making a copy by `obj = {...foo}` shouldn't affect the original foo right. ?
It should only change obj, and not foo

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas so the expected output is `[1, 5, 10, 15, 9, 12, "Star Flash"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you get the reference of the `List` property.

```
let myList = obj[key].List;
```

And then in the bottom, you splice it. ( splice will effect the origin array as it has the same referance )

```
const spliced = [...myList.splice(index, 1, resList)];
```

It should be

```
let myList = [...obj[key].List];
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it should be **deep copied**

Inner props will have the **same reference** (as it is not deep copied, only the object is spreaded & not its props)

Any changes to the **copyObj** **non-primitives** will reflect in **object** also. (only **object** & **copyObject** will have different refs)

for e.g ,

```js
var object = {a:[1,2,4],b:[2,3]}
var copyObj = {...object}

console.log(object===copyObj);

console.log(object.a===copyObj.a);

copyObj.a.push(1);

console.log(...object.a)
console.log(...copyObj.a)
```